# How to configure running selected tests in a complex FitNesse suite?

Tags: fitnesse

We have a complex Fitnesse suite with tens of subsuites, includes and symbolic links. Sometimes we don't want to run the whole thing and would like to run
**selected test cases and not run the others**. We see two ways to do it:

1. By managing page properties (Suite - Test - Normal), we can turn on/off test cases.

   But this is inconvenient. First of all, it's boring. And second, we can't see the suite current state (what test cases are turned on and gonna be run).
2. In Fitnesse, [there are tags](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuites.TagsAndFilters), and we can specify desired tags in suiteFilter or excludeSuiteFilter.

   This is inconvenient too. You have to remember tag names and don't forget or misspell them in filters. Of course, we can store predefined links with carefully selected lists of tags, but in our case it's not the option, since the lists are subject to frequent changes.

Also, we don't want to divide our suite on several parts, since we benefit from having the general Scenario Library and variable lists.

The ideal solution for us would be having a Fitnesse suite configurator, which could display and change settings of Fitnesse pages. Say, it may be a Fitnesse plugin, which read Fitnesse folder structure and display current settings in an html page or with Windows Form, letting change these settings and save the changes. Or an external tool with similar functionality.

Have you heard of such tools? Did you bump into the same troubles? What would be your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that the first option you listed, manipulating the page properties is a bad idea.  It will cause pain in the log run.

I would note that tags area very reasonable approach.  The thing to keep in mind about tags filets is that you can build links that will run all of the tests tagged a specific value and make that a part of the FrontPage

For example, you can put a link in your FrontPage that will run all tests marked "smoke".
[[Run Smoke Tests][.FrontPage.MonsterSuite?suite&suiteFilter=smoke]]

There is one other variation on selective execution you could do, but I've not been as successful with.  Take a look at SuiteQuery: http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuites.SuiteQuery.

SuiteQuery is a technique that lets you specify a suite by building a table that lists the pages or page name filters to run.

```
!|Suite|
|Page|FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests|
|Content|[Bb]ug|

!|Suite|
|Page|FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests|
|Title|Import|
```

Comment: Hi Dan! In our environment, we would have hundreds of different tags. It's hard to cover all tag combinations with predefined links. More promising approach is to configure the suite based on current needs. You have to remember tag names and don't forget or misspell them in filters. Of course, we can store predefined links with carefully selected lists of tags, but in our case it's not the option, since the lists are subject to frequent changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way..

Create a new suite and add the following code to it..

```
!see .FrontPage.TestPage
```